# is the word "string" inside the string is a reserved word in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a question about the third line in those both codes:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, "text", 4, 5, 6];
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (typeof array[i] !== "string") continue;
  console.log(array[i]);
}
```

result:

> text

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, "text", 4, 5, 6];
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (typeof array[i] !== "") continue;
  console.log(array[i]);
}
```

result:

> 

Q: the difference are the "" and the "string", is the word "string" is a reserved word in Javascript? what I know is that inside the strings there no reserved words, but why the conclusion is different?

Comment: `typeof` gives you a string which contains what type your thing is. You’re making a string comparison with that. In your second case, none of those strings are equal to `""`, so nothing is printed…

Comment: The `typeof ` operator returns a string indicating the type(data type) of the operand. In your case typeof  "text" will be "string" and you are just comparing 2 strings. That's y "string" will work while "" won't

Comment: The typeof operator evaluates to a string, which will be one of: "number", "string", "undefined", "object", "boolean", "function", "bigint", or "symbol". It is never "".

Comment: How can I tell it that I want it to see the strings, not the numbers?

Comment: Well, you already are!? Your first example does exactly that.

Comment: I asked my teacher he told me that both will work. but it seems that it's not correct

Comment: Indeed, the second won’t work.

Comment: Yes, that's true the first one does exactly that.. yes.

Comment: Okay thank you Deceze I'll tell my instructor about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
typeof 1
```

Result is number

```
typeof 'Text'
```

Result is string

so when you check this condition `(typeof array[i] !== "")`
it will give true in all cases when array is `[1, 2, 3, "text", 4, 5, 6];` so it will continue the execution and result will be blank ;

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is set so that if it does not equal the specified type, then it should continue to the next iteration.

Since the type will never be "", then it skips all the entries for logging.